# Excel 2016 Complex IF statement from multiple sheets adding data from one to the other if a condition is true

Tags: excel

So I've been asked to perform a function in a workbook that has me confused a little. I have used nested If statements so I think that's where I need to start but I don't know how to formulate it. So it goes something like this...

IF data on Sheet 4 Column A is a match to data on Sheet 8 Column Q Then place calendar Date From Sheet 4 Column G in Sheet 8 Column S.

Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in `Sheet8!S1`:

```
=IF(Sheet4!A1=Sheet8!Q1,Sheet4!<calendar date>,"didn't match")
```

You didn't tell us what column the calendar date is in on Sheet4 so I've left that bit for you to fill in.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!  Your expertise is appreciated and I nearly had it I just couldn't put it all together! :)  The Calendar Date is from Sheet 4 Column G to be placed in Sheet 8 Column S.  However when I did this it just put Didn't Match in all the column boxes.  This is because the rows aren't equally matched row for row.  Would I use something like VLookup to search Sheet 4 for a match? And how do I do that I've never used it before.

Comment: I tried it by using a range.  That didn't work either.  Looked like this:  =IF9Sheet4!A2:2000=Sheet8!Q2,Sheet8!S2=Sheet4!G2:2000)  It's a matching problem.  But I just don't know how to complete the match.